# How to count an specific element row/column wise in ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Is there any numpy function that would count, lets say, 0's(or any other element) in every row(or column)? e.g.

```
[4]
[3]
[4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By performing a comparison `A == 0`, numpy returns an array of booleans, which you can then sum over as they are interpreted as 1's and 0's for `True` and `False` respectively:

```py
>>> A = np.array([
...     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
...     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
...     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
... ])
>>> np.sum(A == 0, axis=0)
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1])
>>> np.sum(A == 0, axis=1)
array([3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Why not use `count_nonzero`?

Comment: Eh... Because I never really use it myself? :P I'll update the answer to include it later, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` on a boolean masked array

```
(arr == number).sum(1)
```

---

```
>>> (arr == 0).sum(1)
array([4, 4, 4])

>>> (arr == 1).sum(1)
array([2, 2, 2])
```

Can always reshape at the end

```
>>> (arr == 0).sum(1).reshape(-1,1)
array([[4],
       [4],
       [4]])
```

Comment: Instead of the reshape you can also use `keepdims=1`